# How to get timezone abbreviation only from offset in java script

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

I have datetime string like "2020-09-18T15:10:10-06:00", So how do I get timezone abbreviation (EST, CST,..) from offset (-06:00) with javascript. Can anyone give me solution?

Comment: what if multiple time zone abbreviations share the same UTC offset?

Comment: You can't reliably determine the timezone name from the offset, as names aren't standardised and often multiple timezones share the same offset.